# Ionic diagnostic plugin error when building with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization')
checkLocationSettings@file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/17-714B2421w-12AD-A13E-17245G12B039/MyApp.app/www/js/app.js:264:35
```

I checked the installed plugins and I can see that I have this installed: `cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.6.5 "Diagnostic"` when I do `cordova plugin ls`

An in my `config.xml` file, I have this:

```
<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="~3.6.5"/>
```

So I'd expect it would work, but it doesn't. I am trying to get it to work for the iPhone 7 (physical device, not the simulator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An in my index.html file, I have this:
>
> `<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="~3.6.5"/>`

I hope you mean `config.xml` not `index.html`.

> Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization')

The error is indicative of the plugin either not being present in the app or being referenced before it has been dynamically loaded by Cordova.

Firstly, check the plugin is actually present in the app. You can check in XCode if the plugin files `diagnostic.js` and `Diagnostic.m` are present in your project.

Secondly, ensure you are not referencing the plugin before the `deviceready` event has fired, since it will not be loaded.

See the [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example) for a working example of the plugin.

Comment: Hmm. So, diagnostic.js and Diagnostic.m are files I need to have? And in what folder should they be in, to be exact? I can see cordova.plugins.diagnostic in my plugins folder and also a Diagnostic.m file in the ios folder... but no diagnostic.js file. Is there a way / command I can add that one? Edit: oh yes, I've found diagnostic.js too (in www), yet I can't see them in Xcode... I only see them in my IDE.

Comment: Interesting. I have a folder called "Staging"... there, the whole diagnostic plugin is not loaded. Could that be the problem? Is that something I can fix with the ios.json file or isn't this relevant at all? I don't know what the Staging folder is and what it should do, at the moment...

Comment: In Xcode, `Staging` is `your_project/platforms/ios/` - i.e. the native iOS project. `www/` is `your_project/www` - i.e. the Cordova project. . There should exist `Staging/www/plugins/cordova.plugins.diagnostic/www/ios/diagnostic.js` and `Plugins/Diagnostic.m&.h`.

Comment: Ah... that one does not exist (in staging). How is that even possible, when it is installed in the Cordova project? Could you elaborate and tell me how to fix it?

Comment: `cordova plugin rm cordova.plugins.diagnostic; cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic@latest; cordova prepare ios`

Comment: I think you are the king of this, so that's why I am asking this: do you know whether the whitelist plugin should be in the staging folder as well? Cause whatever I do, I can't get it in there... do you have any tips?

Comment: @Siyah There's a good reason it's not in the Staging folder: it's an Android-only plugin - check the [plugin.xml](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/plugin.xml#L33)

Comment: Ah, shoot! And where can I see which plugins must be in the staging folder for iOS then? Beside that: can you help me with how to log the errors in Xcode? Safari is not giving errors, while the app keeps loading and loading. Do you have any insider tips?